What is a good way to smooth/filter out clustered data points in recorded navigation time series trajectory data in MATLAB?
I have data sets of recorded navigation trajectories in x and y accompanied with t for time point at that x, y position. However, there are some areas on the trajectory where the navigator has been stuck at that x, y area so there are clustered data points in that area.
What is a good way to remove the clustered data points?
I attached an example of one data set of the raw x, y data position points connected with segments.Example of raw x, y data points with segments connected in a sequence
I have tried subsampling but does not do the job I am seeking since the navigator can be stuck in an area for a "long" time. I tried smoothdata() with 'rloess' where it does a good job in some areas but in some straight paths, it turns it squiggly.
My ultimate goal is to create as straight of a segment of the navigation trajectory as possible to give an idea of the navigator's body position in space.Here is an example of a 200 smoothing factor on the raw data which fixes majority but still need to remove the clustered areas
Would a moving average smoothing function work better? Please give me some ideas!
Many thanks!
